# Wrapping a COM object/dynamic type in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, com, dynamic, c#-4.0

I am currently working with COM objects in managed code and am using the new dynamic type for this. This works well in some areas but can be an issue in others.

I was think about how I could get the best of both worlds, the flexibility of the dynamic type (late bound) with the support for say, an RCW (early bound)

Somehow wrapping the dynamic type in a more manageable stucture. I was wondering if there was a preferred method for this (if it is even a good idea) or what things I should consider.

The two basic ideas I came up with so far as follows:

Firstly, creating a static class that allows me to call the methods of the dynamic type in a managed way.

```
public static class ComObjectWrapper
{
   public static void SomeMethod(dynamic comObject, int x)
   {
      comObject.someMethod(x);
   }

   public static bool GetSomeProp(dynamic comObject)
   {
      comObject.getSomeProp();
   }

   public static void SetSomeProp(dynamic comObject, bool foo)
   {
      comObject.setSomeProp(foo);
   }
}
```

Secondly, creating a class that is constructed using the com object, then mapping all its members to managed properties, methods, etc.

```
public class ComObjectWrapper
{
   private dynamic comObject = null;

   public ComObjectWrapper(dynamic comObject)
   {
     this.comObject = comObject;
   }

   public void SomeMethod(int x)
   {
      comObject.someMethod(x);
   }

   public bool SomeProp
   {
      get
      {
         return comObject.getSomeProp();
      }
      set
      {
         comObject.setSomeProp(value);
      }
   }
}
```

Are there other ways to approach this? Am I missing something stupid!?

Comment: If you have the option for an RCW at all then using *dynamic* makes no sense.  Almost all COM servers support it, import the type library.

Comment: Sorry I don't agree at all - for example; if the type library, which is outside my control, is updated then any application based on its RCW is broken. Secondly, what about all the versions of the type  library, I can only target one version. Essentially I want to late-bind to avoid version dependence on a library I have no control over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opensource framework [Impromptu-Interface](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/) will wrap a dynamic object with a static interface such that all the statically defined members from the interface use the dlr to forward to the dynamic object.

Create Your interface

```
IComObjectWrapper
{
   void SomeMethod(int x);
   bool SomeProp;
}
```

Then where you need to wrap your com object include ImpromptuInterface

```
  using ImpromptuInterface;
```

And finally to wrap it:

```
var tStaticTyped = Impromptu.ActLike<IComObjectWrapper>(comObject);
```

Comment: This sounds interesting - I will give it a go now!